# Biuld a Box up Puzzle game

Tags: logical-deduction, puzzle-creation

I want to build a [box up puzzle](https://www.mathsisfun.com/games/boxup-puzzle.html) game. I am struggling to implement this. Can you all suggest some sources or logic to implement it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, Shashwat! Puzzling.SE requires that questions be self-contained - could you pleas edit your question to include the requirements of the box up puzzle? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question asking about how to implement a puzzle in programming, and not actually a puzzle.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Programming advice is off-topic for this site, both because it's not directly related to puzzles and because it's too broad to be given a direct answer.

Comment: @op it is unlikely that you'll find an answer to your question on any stack exchange site, you'll have to either try your best or seek an alternative source of help.